# ToroPlayer is not playing video in recycler-view adapter in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
class SelfPostDetailPageVideoViewHolder(
    itemView: View,
    val context: Context,
    val appClick: SingleLiveData<SelfPostDetailPageWidget.CallToAction>
) : BaseViewHolder<PostsList>(itemView), LayoutContainer, ToroPlayer {
    override val containerView = itemView

    lateinit var playerView: PlayerView

    lateinit var state: TextView

    private var helper: ExoPlayerViewHelper? = null
    private var mediaUri: Uri? = null

    override fun bind(item: PostsList) {
        itemView.apply {
            playerView = findViewById(R.id.ivPostVideo)
            state = findViewById(R.id.tvState)
            groupImage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            playerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            txtProfileName.text = item.createdBy.name
            mediaUri = Uri.parse(item.videos[0].url)

        }
    }


    private val listener: Playable.EventListener = object : Playable.DefaultEventListener() {
        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
            super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
            itemView.tvState.text = String.format(
                Locale.getDefault(),
                "STATE: %d・PWR: %s",
                playbackState,
                playWhenReady
            )
        }
    }

    override fun getPlayerView(): View {
        return this.playerView
    }

    override fun getCurrentPlaybackInfo(): PlaybackInfo {
        return helper?.latestPlaybackInfo ?: PlaybackInfo()
    }

    override fun initialize(container: Container, playbackInfo: PlaybackInfo) {
        checkNotNull(mediaUri) { "mediaUri is null." }
        if (helper == null) {
            mediaUri?.let {
                helper = ExoPlayerViewHelper(this, it)
            }
            helper?.addEventListener(listener)
        }
        helper?.initialize(container, playbackInfo)
    }

    override fun play() {
        if (helper != null) helper?.play()
    }

    override fun pause() {
        if (helper != null) helper!!.pause()
    }

    override fun isPlaying(): Boolean {
        return helper != null && helper?.isPlaying == true
    }

    override fun release() {
        if (helper != null) {
            helper?.removeEventListener(listener)
            helper?.release()
            helper = null
        }
    }

    override fun wantsToPlay(): Boolean {
        return ToroUtil.visibleAreaOffset(this, itemView.parent) >= 0.85
    }

    override fun getPlayerOrder(): Int {
        return adapterPosition
    }
}
```

This is my view holder to automatic play video in recycler-view like instagram and youtube for sort video .
I am able to display video name and its calling bindview method in adapter but its not coming in initialize overriden method of ToroPlayer so video is not playing can any one help me what i am doing mistake how i can play  automatic video using ToroPlayer .

Thanks